# How to get message value from this object

Tags: php, laravel, object

I am getting below output from laravel

I need to get only message from her but unable to get

I am getting this object in `$bar` variable

```
FatalThrowableError {#20 ▼
  #message: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Route' (T_STRING), expecting '{'"
  #code: 0
  #line: 36
  #severity: E_PARSE
  -trace: {▶}
}
```

I tried `$bar->message`

Actually I made this error intentionally, I am storing error in table. so I just want to get `message` part only.

***Update***

I asked this question because I wanted to to store error in mysql and it is possible through laravel events named `illuminate.log` it gives two param one for type and another is for message collection with file-name, line number and all, so I asked how to get only message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get error message by `$bar->getMessage()`,

I asked this question because I wanted to to store error in mysql and it is possible through laravel events named `illuminate.log` it gives two param one for type and another is for message collection with file-name, line number and all, so I asked how to get only message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try/catch Block for this purpose please take a look below i am writing a sample code

```
$response = null;
try{
    //Your Code, Operations
}catch(\Exception $e){
    $response = $e->getMessage();
}
return $response;
```

Comment: actually I made this error intentionally, I am storing error in table. so I just want to get `message` part only.

Comment: I am able to get error message by $bar->getMessage(), Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Your 'object' is a PHP syntax error. You should check your code for syntax errors. The `message` attribute is protected (#) and therefore cannot be accessed.

Comment: actually I made this error intentionally, I am storing error in table. so I just want to get `message` part only

Comment: You can't. Your script will exit as soon as this FatalError is thrown. It's called `FatalThrowableError` for a reason. I don't recall this being a regular PHP exception

Comment: I am able to get error message by $bar->getMessage(), Thanks for your reply